# C# Threads Como otimizar um SELECT com BLOB

Tags: c#, mysql, thread, blob

Tenho uma aplicação em C# (.Net 4.5) que ao carregar uma tela dentre outras operações ele buscar no banco de dados uma imagem de fundo e sons. 
Acontece que para algumas telas carregadas essa operação (buscar imagens + sons) demora 29 segundos, o que ocasiona uma péssima experiência ao usuário.
Gostaria de criar algo para que esse tempo caísse.
Implementei 2 Threads uma para cada operação, porém o tempo de execução pulou para 31 segundos.
Alguém tem uma solução para melhorar isso?

```
    Task t1 = new Task(CarregarImagens);
    t1.Start();

    Task t2 = new Task(CarregarSons);
    t2.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

*Threading*, por si só, não torna o processo mais rápido; a prática permite a você paralelizar seu processamento, o que pode ser um grande benefício se seus processos entram em *WaitState* com frequência.

Uma solução seria a obtenção das imagens e sons em um ponto anterior do processo, em estilo de *pre-fetching*. Assim, os recursos estariam disponíveis de imediato quando o usuário os solicitar.

Comment: Entendi. Esse sistema é um sistema desenvolvido para rodar cursos didáticos, antes do aluno logar e selecionar a aula que vai assistir não há como eu carregar as telas.

Comment: @LeandroSJRP , imagino - esta é uma questão mais da implementação atual do que de `threading`. Você pode tentar otimizar o tempo de várias maneiras: compactando os recursos, reduzindo resolução/bitrates, etc.

Comment: antes de partir para qualquer solução eu levantei isso junto a equipe. Porém, descartaram essa ideia dizendo que o banco de cursos é imenso e para substituição dos cursos seria inviável. Bom... Paciência né!? Mas valeu pelas dicas.

Comment: Infelizmente você está limitado pela escolhas, @LeandroSJRP . =/ Talvez valha a pena levantar a possibilidade de segmentação do seu banco mySql. De qualquer maneira, boa sorte!

Comment: Valeu! Obrigado!